# Why WordPress custom php code for pagination cannot go to next page

Tags: pagination

Link before I click search: https://nama-sistem.com/carian/

Link after I click search (by name, month, year, theme): https://nama-sistem.com/carian/?nama=abx&month=july&years=2022&theme=flower

When I click next button it not go to next page. Link for next page is supposed like this: https://nama-sistem.com/carian/?nama=abx&month=july&years=2022&theme=flower&page=2

This is my pagination code:

```
$name = (isset($_GET['nama'])) ? $_GET['nama'] : "";
$month = (isset($_GET['month'])) ? $_GET['month'] : "";
$years = (isset($_GET['years'])) ? $_GET['years'] : "";
$theme = (isset($_GET['theme'])) ? $_GET['theme'] : "";

$limit = 10;
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;   

<ul class="pagination pull-right">
if ($name && $month && $years && $theme) {
                $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '$name' AND month LIKE '$month' AND year LIKE '$years' AND theme LIKE '%$theme%' LIMIT $offset, $limit");
            }
            $prev_page = $page - 1;
            $next_page = $page + 1;
            $adjacents = "1";
            $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($query1);
            $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);

            if ($page == 1) {
                echo "<li class='disabled'><a href=''>Previous</a></li>";
            } else {
                echo "<li><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=$prev_page'>Previous</a></li>";
            }

            if ($total_pages <= 7) {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $total_pages; $counter++) {
                    if ($counter == $page) {
                        echo "<li class='active'><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<li><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($total_pages >= 7) {
                if ($page < 5) {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter <= 5; $counter++) {
                        if ($counter == $page) {
                            echo "<li class='active'><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<li><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                        }
                    }
                    if ($counter == $page) {
                        echo "<li><a>...</a></li>";
                        echo "<li class='active'><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=$total_pages'>$total_pages</a></li>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<li><a>...</a></li>";
                        echo "<li><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=$total_pages'>$total_pages</a></li>";
                    }
                } elseif ($page >= 5 && $page <= $total_pages - 4) {
                    echo "<li><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    echo "<li><a>...</a></li>";
                    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++) {
                        if ($counter == $page) {
                            echo "<li class='active'><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<li><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                        }
                    }
                    if ($counter == $page) {
                        echo "<li><a>...</a></li>";
                        echo "<li class='active'><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=$total_pages'>$total_pages</a></li>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<li><a>...</a></li>";
                        echo "<li><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=$total_pages'>$total_pages</a></li>";
                    }
                } elseif ($page <= $total_pages) {
                    echo "<li><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    echo "<li><a>...</a></li>";
                    for ($counter = $total_pages - 4; $counter <= $total_pages; $counter++) {
                        if ($counter == $page) {
                            echo "<li class='active'><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<li><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($page >= $total_pages) {
                echo "<li class='disabled'><a href=''>Next</a></li>";
            } else {
                echo "<li><a href='?nama=$name&month=$month&years=$years&theme=$theme&page=$next_page'>Next</a></li>";
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: If `carian` is a Page (post type `page`) that you added via the Pages → Add New screen at `wp-admin`, then you should use the parameter named `paged` and not `page`. You should also instead use [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) to prepare your SQL query, and `$wpdb->get_var()` (with `COUNT(*)`) to get the number of rows in your table. Those ampersands in the URL, should also be *escaped*, i.e. use `&amp;`, or better, escape the entire URL using [`esc_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/).

Comment: carian is GET page type

Comment: Well, how are you loading the pagination file, and in what template are you loading it? E.g. Did you do something like `include 'custom-pagination.php';` from within your `page.php` template in `wp-content/themes/your-theme`? Also, you said, "*Link for next page is supposed like this*", so what did the link look like instead? Please add the details to your post.

Comment: I doesn't not include any file in my template.. I already  put my full code in my post..

Comment: Yeah, I already saw it. So are you sure this is a WordPress website? I don't see any WordPress-specific code used in your code. If you're just having an issue with a generic PHP-based page, then that has nothing to do with WordPress, and thus you should instead ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, I make the code in my WordPress website in plugins (Insert PHP Code Snippets). So, do I need to change my code to specific code in WordPress?  If  I need to change the code, how to change the code because I not familiar with WordPress Code

Comment: It's better if you use a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) with a [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) or [shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/shortcode/), nonetheless, the issue with your code is likely because you used `page` instead of `paged` or another parameter name which isn't reserved in WordPress.

Comment: So for example, try using `page_num` instead - `$page = (isset($_GET['page_num'])) ? (int) $_GET['page_num'] : 1;` - and replace all the `&page=` instances in your link URL with `&page_num=`. *Additionally, those `?name=` should instead be `?nama=`* ..